# Minix: undefined reference to 'strtok'?

Tags: c, strtok, minix

I am trying to add a new system call at: `/usr/src/servers/pm/exec.c`

I write a very simple method in `exec.c`:

```
void parseBlack(char * value){
    char * ptr = strtok(values, ";");

    }
```

However, when I try to compile it there is an error:

```
In function parseBlac, undefined reference to "strtok".
```

And I have added `#include <string.h>`

It is weird. I checked minix api. It has this method:

/minix/include/string.h(http://code.metager.de/source/xref/minix/include/string.h)

Here is a screen shot:

[image]

Comment: It's a linker error. Do you need to explicitly link with `libc` (or whatever)? Or just forgo the use of `strtok`.

Comment: strtok is in"/minix/include/string.h", I am not famailiar with "explicity link", can you give me more information about it? How should I "link explicit libc" here? Thanks

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of error messages; copy-and-paste the text so we can read it more easily. You should use `#include <string.h>`, not `#include "string.h"`, but that's not likely to be the cause of the problem. There's a big difference between the ordinary user space environment and the kernel environment; some of the standard library isn't going to be available in the kernel (since the standard library is implemented partially *on top of* the kernel). I'm not familiar with Minux, so I don't know the details.

Answer (score 4):

Servers in MINIX do not link with the full, bloated and verbose `libc.a`, rather with a limited version of the C library (probably `libminc` in your case). Clearly `strtok` was not considered to be part of that limited library in the release you are using. Either move `strtok.c` to that library (edit `libminc/Makefile` then clean and rebuild), or link explicitly with `strtok.o`.