# Linker Complains Undefined Reference Under MINIX3.2.1

Tags: c, makefile, operating-system, kernel, minix

As you may imagine, it's a homework of Operating Systems and I'm asked to add function key <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to show the number of running process.

I read the source code of command `ps` on [GitHub](https://github.com/jncraton/minix3/blob/master/commands/ps/ps.c) (MINIX version 3.2.1) and try to implement a function that can finish the task in file `/usr/src/servers/is/dmp_kernel.c`. However, when I try to run `make`, it complains about undefined reference like

```
dmp_kernel.o: In function `running_proc_num':
dmp_kernel.c:(.text+0x1e): undefined reference to `chdir'
dmp_kernel.c:(.text+0x42): undefined reference to `fopen'
dmp_kernel.c:(.text+0x72): undefined reference to `fscanf'
dmp_kernel.c:(.text+0x8b): undefined reference to `fclose'
dmp_kernel.c:(.text+0xc4): undefined reference to `log10'
dmp_kernel.c:(.text+0xcc): undefined reference to `ceil'
dmp_kernel.c:(.text+0x119): undefined reference to `log10'
dmp_kernel.c:(.text+0x121): undefined reference to `ceil'
dmp_kernel.c:(.text+0x170): undefined reference to `fopen'
dmp_kernel.c:(.text+0x1bc): undefined reference to `fscanf'
dmp_kernel.c:(.text+0x1d3): undefined reference to `fclose'
dmp_kernel.c:(.text+0x210): undefined reference to `wait'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I've already include the headers like `stdio.h`, `math.h`, `unistd.h`, and `sys/wait.h`. In the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26947282/minix-undefined-reference-to-strtok) to one Stack Overflow question, I learnt that the reason for this issue is that the linker doesn't link a complete C library under MINIX. However, I usually use `CMake` and really have no idea to solve such issue. I don't even know how to "explicitly" link the functions using `make`.

I really look forward for your help!

---

The `Makefile` looks like

```
.include <bsd.own.mk>

PROG=   is
SRCS=   main.c dmp.c dmp_kernel.c dmp_pm.c dmp_fs.c dmp_rs.c dmp_ds.c dmp_vm.c

DPADD+= ${LIBSYS}
LDADD+= -lsys

MAN=

BINDIR?= /sbin

CPPFLAGS.dmp_kernel.c+= -I${NETBSDSRCDIR}
CPPFLAGS.dmp_rs.c+=     -I${NETBSDSRCDIR}
CPPFLAGS.dmp_vm.c+=     -I${NETBSDSRCDIR}

# This setting must match the kernel's, as it affects the IRQ hooks table size.
.if ${USE_APIC} != "no"
CFLAGS+= -DUSE_APIC
.endif

.include <minix.service.mk>
```

Comment: It's probably a Makefile issue, so you need to look in the Makefile. -l is usually used to link libraries.

Comment: You need to find out which library contains the missing function. Then add it to the list of libraries.

Comment: Well. I used another method to solve the homework, but I still don't know how to explicitly link a library by makefile.